# Use data from aggregate function in another SOQL query

Tags: apex

I am querying my data using an aggregate function to get the Max date
and I would like to use that max Date into another query but I do not manage to use the data or the Date is not a date anymore..

My code is the following:

```
public class ApprovalTable {
    public ApprovalTable(){
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<wrapperClass> getWrapperClassList() {
       List<wrapperClass> wrapperList = new List<wrapperClass>();
       for(Opportunity Opp: [select id, name, StageName from Opportunity]){
           wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();
           List<AggregateResult> IC_max_date_data = [SELECT Opportunity__c, max(date__c) maxDate 
                                                  FROM Approval__c WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id 
                                                  AND Type__c = 'Investment_Committee' 
                                                  AND date__c != Null 
                                                  GROUP BY Opportunity__c];
           for(AggregateResult date_item: IC_max_date_data){
               
               String date_used = date_item.get('maxDate').toString() ;
           }

           system.debug('Max Date Last ' + :date_used);
           if (IC_max_date_data.isEmpty()){
               wc.icDate = Null;
               wc.icStatus = Null;
           } else {
               List<Approval__c> IC_Approval_data = [SELECT date__c, Status__c 
                                                    FROM Approval__c
                                                    WHERE Opportunity__r.Id = :Opp.Id
                                                    AND date__c = <FIELD MAX DATE FROM IC_MAX DATE DATE>
                                                    ];
           }
           
          
           wc.OppName = Opp.name;
           wc.OppStage = Opp.StageName;
           wrapperList.add(wc);
       }
        
       return wrapperList;
   }
    
   public class wrapperClass{
       @AuraEnabled public String OppName;
       @AuraEnabled public String OppStage;
       @auraEnabled public Object maxDataData;
       @auraEnabled public date icDate;
       @auraEnabled public String icStatus;
   }    
}
```

I tried using a loop, I tried to get .get .. I tried expr0. Using the loop the object is not a Date anymore but looks like Fri Jun 11 00:00:00 GMT 2021

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String date_used = date_item.get('maxDate').toString() ;
```

You turned it in to a string using default formatting, so of course it's formatted differently.

Instead, you can just get the date:

```
DateTime date_used = (DateTime)date_item.get('maxDate');
```

Comment: Is there a way to get to that data without using the For Loop. ? my query IC_max_date_data return only 1 value ..

Comment: turning it into a string was a failed test .. because nothing else seems to work

Comment: @Ben2pop You can check `IC_max_date_data[0].get('maxDate')`, then.